# How do I poll data from Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have deployed a contract.

Now I would like to periodically poll it for data.

I can do this one time by opening geth, using my abi statement, creating a contract variable and then interrogating that contract instance.

But how do I do this in a scripted way that I can call from a cron job?

Comment: Total hack, but can't you put the geth commands in a file and do this in your cron: cat file > geth console.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of polling data from a storage variable for changes the clean way would be by using [events](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events). When changing your storage variable you might fire an event - if the storage variable does not need to be available to other smart contracts you might even omit the storage variable totally and only go via events (events cannot be accessed from other contracts).

These [events create logs](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e) in the blockchain. Then, instead of polling you can subscribe to the event, e.g. via the [web3.js](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-logs) library and handle events. Whenever the event fires you have an event handler in nodeJS (there are also python or java libraries) that could execute some server logic.